# how to save multiple text file with different names in a loop

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to save some text that i extract by web scraping and selenium web driver from multiple web page in a for loop.
the problem is i can not change the file name for next action and im facing with this System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'

```
for (int i = 0; i < news.Count; i++)
{
var heading = title.Text;
var body = articleBody.Text;
var name = id.Text + date.Text; // its different and unique for each page

File.WriteAllText($"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\name{name}.txt", heading + body);
}`
```

Comment: this is not selenium related

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your current code is that you are specifying the file path as a string literal with the file name enclosed in quotes, like this: `"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\name{name}.txt"`. Because of this, the file name is not being constructed properly and is being treated as a literal string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < news.Count; i++)
{
    var heading = title.Text;
    var body = articleBody.Text;
    var name = id.Text + date.Text; // its different and unique for each page
    
    // Construct the file path and name
    string filePath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\";
    string fileName = $"name{name}.txt";
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
    
    // Write the text to the file
    File.WriteAllText(fullPath, heading + body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the name of the file you are trying to save. You cannot use special characters like '/' or ':' in the file name. In your code, the variable 'name' contains special characters that are not allowed in the file name format. Try modifying the variable 'name' to remove any special characters before using it in the file name.

you can try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < news.Count; i++)
{
var heading = title.Text;
var body = articleBody.Text;
var name = id.Text + date.Text;
name = new string(name.Where(c => !char.IsPunctuation(c)).ToArray()); // remove special characters
File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\Desktop{name}.txt", heading + body);
}
```

it removes any special characters from the 'name' variable using LINQ and saves the text files in the format "name.txt" in the specified directory.